# New blog created with Wordpress is not crawlable by sitemap software

Tags: sitemap

I have a new blog at glowingstart.com (didn't want to add it to the question, but the domain is needed to verify that it can't be crawled by that sitemap-generating site) and I was trying to use this site http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/ to create a sitemap. I have created sitemaps for other sites there and it worked fine.

But with this new site, I got an error. Is there some setting which prevents crawling that Wordpress has? Or what may be the reason for this?

Thank you!

Comment: "*I got an error.*" - **what error**, exactly, did you get? Also, have you set your WordPress install to private (i.e. not crawlable)?

Comment: @ChipBennett The error message is something that does not make sense. But could you please help me understand how I can determine whether the site is crawlable? You can certainly access it on the web.

Comment: Please include the actual error message in your question. Regarding site privacy settings, go to `Dashboard -> Settings -> Reading`, and look for the option **Search Engine Visibility**.